# What is needed to get javascript to pull a file from Google Cloud Storage with auth control?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm trying to change my Tamper/Grease monkey userscript to pull updates from GCS. While this is usually trivial if the storage is public, the file URL requires verification that the user is a member from our domain. There in lies the problem.

If the URL is accessed via the browser, it bounces around some redirects for Google Auth, and eventually retrieves the file and will "remember the login" for some time. This is a manual intervention process and is not a transparent solution.

If I pull the file when auth isn't known (ie: new browser), I get a 302 redirect, which when run under the userscript scope in TamperMonkey is simply treated as an error, and not followed (This is part of the RFQ from memory).

Now, if I use the script to push the URL as a link in the page, the link works (domain auth already in use to access the page). If I use the script to access the link, the tokens aren't available (guess?), and so a 302 takes place, and because it's in script land, it silently fails.

I'm looking to find out what JS I need to import, to pull any required auth tokens that the user already has, and send them along with the request to the GCS location. Note that Google Auth is required to be using the underlying website, and usernames will be on the required domain.

The GCS file has Domain:Reader permissions set with our domain listed.

Comment: I think you need to further clarify this statement "...find out what JS is needed to import to pull any required auth tokens....". The [Link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#obtainingaccesstokens) describes how to use the Google APIs client library for JavaScript to handle the OAuth 2.0 flow. About accessing the Google Cloud Storage, You can review the details on [how to use the Google Cloud Client Library in your Node.js app to store data in and retrieve data from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-storage)

Comment: In hindsight, I concur. I added details that explain if the location is a link and the user clicks on it, it's fine. Access is checked and the appropriate magic happens. BUT, if the link is to be pulled via a Monkey script, this runs isolated from the rest of the experience, and I need to pull certain tokens from the user scope into the monkey scope.

Comment: @AustinArrowsmith were you able to find a solution to this?